# Как сделать чтобы UI Элемент (Текст) появлялся при выполнение определенного действия?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт по перезарядке оружия. Нужно, чтобы при перезарядке появлялся текст `Reloading`, а когда перезарядка не производится, текст исчезал. Как это можно сделать?

Текст сам имеется, нужно прописать его появление при перезарядке и исчезновение, когда ее нет.

```
{        
    public float offset;              
    public Transform firepoint;                    // Точка из которой вылетает пуля
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;                // Объект пули используемый для стрельбы
    public Animator ShootAnimator;                // Анимация применяемая к оружию
    public int amountOfBullets;                    // Количество пуль вылетающее из точки вылета
    public float spread, BulletForce = 1f;         // Разброс пуль и скорость пули
    public float TimeCouldown;                     // Время ожидания, перед следующим выстрелом
    float nextfire;
    public float Range;

    public int maxAmmo = 5;                        // Максимальное кол-во патронов
    public int currentAmmo;                        // Текущее кол-во патронов
    public bool currentlyReloading = false;        // Состояние перезарядки, не менять значение!
    public float reloadTime = 5f;                  // Время перезарядки, менять лишь от оружия.

    public TextMeshProUGUI AmmoInfoText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ReloadingInfoText;

void start()
{        
    currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
}  

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() 
{  
    AmmoInfoText.text = currentAmmo + " / " + maxAmmo;
    
    if (currentlyReloading)
        return;
    
    if (currentAmmo <= 0) StartCoroutine(Reload());
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && currentAmmo != maxAmmo)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
        return;
    }

    Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + offset, Vector3.forward);
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Shoot();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность вам!
Методом проб и ошибок, и извлечения полезной информации из вашего ответа на похожий вопрос, ответ был найден.

Comment: По-моему, у вас должна над вопросом должна появляться плашка с вопросом, действительно ли ваш вопрос является дубликатом предложенного мною. Вы можете отметить да, чтобы закрыть ваш вопрос как дубликат, чтобы будущие пользователи, которые наткнутся на ваш вопрос тоже смогли перейти к тому. Или вы можете поставить галочку на своем ответе, что будет значить, что он принят

Comment: Вопрос указал как дубликат для лучшего поиска данной проблемы другим, здесь можно будет указать после этого свой ответ как правильный?
Чтобы людям было понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ходе разбора, попыток ну и листания форума, и вышеуказанного совета от Максима, за что благодарю его, была написана данная часть кода.
Благодарю всех, за какую либо оказанную помощь.

```
void Update() 
{        
    AmmoInfoText.text = currentAmmo + " / " + maxAmmo;   
    
    if (currentlyReloading)
       ReloadingInfoText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    
    if (currentlyReloading == false)
       ReloadingInfoText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    if (currentlyReloading)            
        return;
    
    if (currentAmmo <= 0) StartCoroutine(Reload());
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && currentAmmo != maxAmmo)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public TextMeshProUGUI ReloadingInfoText;

// Действие при перезарядке
ReloadingInfoText.text = "Перезарядка";

// Действие после перезарядки
ReloadingInfoText.text = null;
```

Comment: Уходи пока можешь с этой сферы. Не быть тебе разработчиком...